# Crash app when using Pod and run Masonry 3.party

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with pod and Masonry 3.party in my project.

1. When I download Masonry 3.party in Github and then I added it in my project. My project is running okey.
2. However, I try it with Pod. `pod 'Masonry'`. When I added Masonry from Pod, my project has a project. It has been crash when I'm running it.

log

`2015-07-15 11:42:18.676 myapp[4249:122126] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView mas_makeConstraints:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa23ba6f740'`

Please help me to solve that problem. Thanks.

Comment: did you follow installation process? https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry#installation

Comment: if it is a problem with a 3rd party software, you might have better luck asking on their forum, mailing-list or bug-tracker. if it is a problem with your code, you have to show your code (minimal example to reproduce the problem, and optimally complete setup instructions to reproduce too).